# How to replace accented characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, non-ascii-characters

My output looks like 'àéêöhello!'. I need change my output like this  **'aeeohello'**, Just replacing the character à as a like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Answer (score 50):

Please Use the below code:

```
import unicodedata

def strip_accents(text):
    try:
        text = unicode(text, 'utf-8')
    except NameError: # unicode is a default on python 3 
        pass

    text = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', text)\
           .encode('ascii', 'ignore')\
           .decode("utf-8")

    return str(text)

s = strip_accents('àéêöhello')

print s
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't work for all the letters (Đ, ı, ł just to name some).

Comment: Why `str(text)`? `normalize` seems to return a string(Python 3.9).

Comment: `NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined` python 3.8

Comment: Works without the block try (text = unicode(text, 'utf-8') gets an error. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 13):

```
import unidecode

somestring = "àéêöhello"

#convert plain text to utf-8
u = unicode(somestring, "utf-8")
#convert utf-8 to normal text
print unidecode.unidecode(u)
```

Output:

```
aeeohello
```

Answer (score 6):

[Alpesh Valaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4952947/alpesh-valaki)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432222/6045800) is the "nicest", but I had to do some adjustments for it to work:

```
# I changed the import
from unidecode import unidecode

somestring = "àéêöhello"

#convert plain text to utf-8
# replaced unicode by unidecode
u = unidecode(somestring, "utf-8")

#convert utf-8 to normal text
print(unidecode(u))
```

Comment: This works for me trying to get stuff like: 'Đà Nẵng' into 'Da Nang' - thanks!