# Understanding the use of encode/decode to strip diacritics

Tags: python, decode, encode, diacritics

I am interested in learning how to strip diacritics from text. That said, I am trying to better understand what's going on in following lines of code, which I found in a post from 2017 ([How to replace accented characters in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431730/how-to-replace-accented-characters-in-python?rq=1)):

`import unicodedata`

`text = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', text).encode('ascii','ignore').decode('utf-8')`

Here is my rough understanding:

`unicodedata.normalize('NFD',text)` translates each character into its decomposed form (e.g. à becomes a), .

`.encode('ascii','ignore')` converts the normalized text into an ascii byte string (`b'string'`) and ignores any errors.

`.decode('utf-8')` returns the string decoded from the given bytes, but this is where I get stuck. Why not use `.decode('ascii')` instead? Are the two encodings overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct. The trick is `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`. ASCII can only express 128 characters, and a lot of those aren't even printable. The ASCII character set certainly contains no characters with diacritics. So it's trying to force the text into the ASCII characters set, and `ignore` causes all characters which it can't express to be silently discarded; which gets rid of all those decomposed diacritics.

You're right that decoding it as UTF-8 doesn't inherently make a lot of sense; decoding it as ASCII would make more sense. But, like a lot of encodings, UTF-8 is a *superset* of ASCII. Any valid ASCII string is also a valid UTF-8 string, or a valid ISO-8859-1 string, or a valid string in a lot of other encodings. You could decode it in any of those compatible encodings and get the same result. The author explicitly choosing UTF-8 is… just slightly bizarre, but technically inconsequential.